# Inner Product of Given Sum Positive Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, linear-programming, inner-product, quadratic-programming

Let $$A = \Big\{(a_1,a_2,\dots)\ \Big|\ a_i\ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i=1\Big\},$$ $$v(x)=\sup\left(\bigg\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_ib_i\ \bigg|\ (a_i)_{i=1}^\infty,\, (b_i)_{i=1}^\infty \in A,\,\sup\limits_{i\in \mathbf N} a_ib_i =x\bigg\}\right).$$ Certainly $v$ is an increasing function. Is $v(x)$ finite for every $x$? Is it achievable? Does $v(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following inequality:

\begin{align*}\sum_{i =1}^\infty a_i b_i & \le \left(\sum_{i = 1}^\infty a_i^2 b_i\right)^{1/2} \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} b_i\right)^{1/2} \\ & \le  \left(\sum_{i = 1}^\infty a_i a_i b_i\right)^{1/2} \\ & \le  \left((\sup_i a_i b_i) \sum_{i =1}^\infty a_i\right)^{1/2}\\ & \le \sqrt{x}.\end{align*}

Hence $\nu(x) \to 0$  as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution. Would you mind I add a very slight alternative?

Comment: Of course not. Would you mind to explain me why you encounter such question?

Comment: I was actually banging my head: why I did not think of this solution earlier... :-/ For the origin of the problem, you can take a look at my answer to my own question http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/cds-spread-and-par-bond-yield-spread/15043#15043.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the solution of Yanqi Qiu, here is a more symmetric derivative of it.

\begin{align}
\Big( \sum_i a_ib_i\Big)^2 &= \Big(\sum_i (a_ib_i)^\frac{1}{2}a_i^\frac{1}{2}b_i^\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2 \\
&\le \sup\limits_i (a_ib_i)\Big(\sum_i a_i^\frac{1}{2}b_i^\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2 \\
&\le \sup\limits_i (a_ib_i)\sum_i a_i\sum_ib_i.
\end{align}